# Doctrine ORM PHP user roles QueryException

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine-query

Issue: **Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException**

> Semantical Error] line 0, col 45 near 'roles IN(:ro': Error: Invalid
> PathExpression. StateFieldPathExpression or
> SingleValuedAssociationField expected.

Caused By:

```
 $qb->select('u')
        ->from(\Eho\Core\Entity\User::class,'u')
        ->where($qb->expr()->in('u.roles',':roleTypes'))
        ->setParameter('roleType', $roleTypes);
```

Where $roleTypes = Object \App\Entity\Role::class  (tested both singular and array of)

Structure and ENV

- Entities: User, Roles
- Tables: user, roles, user_roles

Relationship on Entity User:

```
class User {
:
    @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="\App\User\Entity\Role")
    @ORM\JoinTable(name="user_role",
          joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
          inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="role_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
          )
    private $roles;
```

I've tried several methods (em->findByRoles($role) , $em->findByRoles([$roles]);
which produces:

```
An exception occurred while executing a query: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'user_role.role_id' in 'where clause'
```

The column is on the table user_roles

> CREATE TABLE `user_role` (   `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
> `user_id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,   `role_id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT
> NULL )